# R create edge list

Tags: r, algorithm, networking

New to the Stack Overflow, even though I've been checking what you guys post and answer for quite some time (just didn't have the time to join up while working on my Master's).

TL;DR: I used the script presented here to process a dataset structured like the one below to get edges for a network. It worked but took way too long to process (24h for 2k rows). Any tip to a beginner R user on making it faster?

In my last research project I ended up with a data.frame much like:

```
ID | Trait 1 | Trait 2 | Trait 3 | Trait 4 |  Trait 5
01 |  TRUE   |   TRUE  |  Photo  |   City  |  Portrait
02 |  FALSE  |   TRUE  |  Draw   |  Child  |  Portrait
03 |  TRUE   |  FALSE  |  Photo  |   Misc  |  Landscape
.
.
.
```

And this went on for some 2k rows. The intent was to build a network where each ID is a node, and the sum of common traits between 2 IDs would make up a weighted edge, i.e. ID 01 would have a weight 2 edge to both ID 2 and 3, while ID 2 would not have an edge to ID 3.

To work this out I used the following script that runs through each row comparing each column value to add weight (each match = +1), ignoring rows already compared (being an undirected network, it was unnecessary to match both ways):

Key: Source = ID to compare to; Target = ID being compared; Weight = Sum of matching cells/traits.

```
findEdges <- function(){
    input <- read.csv("nodes.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sep=";")
    edges <- read.csv("edges.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactor=FALSE,skip=1,colClasses=c("integer","integer","integer"),col.names=c("Source","Target","Weight"))    
    for(i in 1:nrow(input)){ #row to be compared: Source
        for(j in 1:nrow(entrada)){ #rows that will compare to: Target
            weight <- 0
            if( i >= j ){
            } else {
                for(k in 1:ncol(input)){ #column by column comparison
                    col <- k
                    if(input[i,k] == input[j,k]){ #edge weight modifier
                        weight <- weight+1
                        }
                }
                print(c("source= ",i,"target= ",j,"weight= ",weight)) #visual feedback of running script
                newRow <- data.frame(Source=i,Target=j,Weight=weight) #create row for compared pair
                edges <- rbind(edges,newRow) # add edge row to data frame
            }
        }
    }
    write.csv(edges,"edges.csv") #write data frame to csv file
}
findEdges()
```

which worked just fine and gave me the weighted edgelist I needed. Each row of the edgelist would be presentes as:

```
Source | Target | Weight
  01   |   02   |   2
  01   |   03   |   2
```

and so on...

However, this script took almost 24h to process the entire dataset (2k rows, 5 columns except ID), and while that was not an issue before, I think it would be nice to check for some tips on a better/faster way to achieve the same results.

Comment: To read some about the (negative) efficiency implications of the line `edges <- rbind(edges, newRow)`, I would suggest Circle 2 of (The R Inferno)[http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf].

Comment: thanks, gonna check on it right away :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to process each column separately, generating pairwise similarity matrix between each of the rows. For instance, let's pretend we're operating on a single column:

```
col <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4)
outer(col, col, "==") * 1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    1    1    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    1    0    1    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    1    0    1    0
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

The `outer` function performs our operator (`==`) between each pair of elements, returning the matrix (the `*1` is just to convert `TRUE`/`FALSE` to 0/1). One nice aspect is that this is a vectorized operator so it will work very quickly compared to an approach involving a for loop.

Now, it's clear that all we need to do is get a similarity matrix for each column and add them all up.

```
(dat <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 2, 3), T1=c(F, F, T), T2=c(T, T, F), T3=c("Photo", "Draw", "Photo"), T4=c("City", "Child", "Misc"), T5=c("Portrait", "Portrait", "Landscape")))
#   ID    T1    T2    T3    T4        T5
# 1  1 FALSE  TRUE Photo  City  Portrait
# 2  2 FALSE  TRUE  Draw Child  Portrait
# 3  3  TRUE FALSE Photo  Misc Landscape
(res <- Reduce("+", lapply(2:ncol(dat), function(x) outer(dat[,x], dat[,x], "=="))))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    5    3    1
# [2,]    3    5    0
# [3,]    1    0    5
```

This function has identified that each row has all 5 columns in common with itself. Further rows 1 and 2 have 3 elements in common, rows 1 and 3 have 1 element in common, and rows 2 and 3 have no elements in common.

You can easily convert at the end from wide to long representation for the graph (here I've filtered out self-links and edges with source id > target id):

```
subset(cbind(expand.grid(Source=dat$ID, Target=dat$ID), Weight=as.vector(res)),
       Source < Target)
#   Source Target Weight
# 4      1      2      3
# 7      1      3      1
# 8      2      3      0
```

Benchmarking shows that the vectorized `outer` function gives us a big advantage over the for loop:

```
set.seed(144)
big.dat <- data.frame(ID=1:100, A=sample(letters, 100, replace=T), B=sample(letters, 100, replace=T), C=sample(1:10, 100, replace=T))
OP <- function(dat) {
  edges <- data.frame(Source=c(), Target=c(), Weight=c())
  for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(dat)) {
      if (i < j) {
        weight <- 0
        for (k in 2:ncol(dat)) {
          if (dat[i,k] == dat[j,k]) {
            weight <- weight + 1
          }
        }
        edges <- rbind(edges, data.frame(Source=i, Target=j, Weight=weight))
      }
    }
  }
  edges
}
josilber <- function(dat) {
  res <- Reduce("+", lapply(2:ncol(dat), function(x) outer(dat[,x], dat[,x], "==")))
  ret <- subset(cbind(expand.grid(Source=dat$ID, Target=dat$ID), Weight=as.vector(res)), Source < Target)
  # Changes to exactly match OP's output
  ret <- ret[order(ret$Source, ret$Target),]
  row.names(ret) <- NULL
  ret
}
all.equal(OP(big.dat), josilber(big.dat))
# [1] TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OP(big.dat), josilber(big.dat), times=10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#               expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
#        OP(big.dat) 5931.354448 6062.872595 6137.497152 6076.736039 6175.002149 6519.977217    10
#  josilber(big.dat)    5.882283    5.914646    6.316981    5.978082    6.368297    8.801991    10
```

We achieved about a 1000x speedup for the example with 100 rows using the vectorized approach.

Comment: oh... this is quite cool. I did not know of outer function, so I'm hitting the documentation on it asap. thanks a lot (gonna try the code and see how it goes)